# Copy PVC files locally without a dedicated pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

We have a `PVC` that is written to by many `k8s` `cronjobs`. We'd like to periodically copy this data locally. Ordinarily one would use `kubectl cp` to do such tasks, but since there's no actively running pod with the `PVC` mounted, this is not possible.

We've been using a modified version of this gist script [kubectl-run-with-pvc.sh](https://gist.github.com/yuanying/3aa7d59dcce65470804ab43def646ab6) to create a temporary pod (running `sleep 300`) and then `kubectl cp` from this temporary pod to get the `PVC` data. This "works" but seems kludgey.

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

May I propose to use NFS instead of PVC?

If you do not have an NFS server, you can run one inside k8s cluster using this image @ https://hub.docker.com/r/itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine. The in-cluster NFS server indeed uses PVC for its storage but your pods should mount using NFS instead.

Meaning, from `pod --> PVC` to `pod --> NFS --> PVC`.

Here is the script that I quite often use to created dedicated in-cluster NFS servers (just modify the variables at the top of the script accordingly):

```
export NFS_NAME="nfs-share"
export NFS_SIZE="10Gi"
export NFS_SERVER_IMAGE="itsthenetwork/nfs-server-alpine:latest"
export STORAGE_CLASS="thin-disk"

kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ${NFS_NAME}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp-2049
    port: 2049
    protocol: TCP
  - name: udp-111
    port: 111
    protocol: UDP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
  name: ${NFS_NAME}
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: ${NFS_SIZE}
  storageClassName: ${STORAGE_CLASS}
  volumeMode: Filesystem
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ${NFS_NAME}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: nfs-server
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ${NFS_NAME}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: ${NFS_SERVER_IMAGE}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2049
          name: tcp
        - containerPort: 111
          name: udp
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: SHARED_DIRECTORY
          value: /nfsshare
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pvc
          mountPath: /nfsshare
      volumes:
      - name: pvc
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: ${NFS_NAME}
EOF
```

To mount the NFS inside your pod, first you need to get its service IP:

```
export NFS_NAME="nfs-share"
export NFS_IP=$(kubectl get --template={{.spec.clusterIP}} service/$NFS_NAME)
```

Then:

```
  containers:
    - name: apache
      image: apache
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/www/html/
          name: nfs-vol
          subPath: html
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-vol
      nfs: 
        server: $NFS_IP
        path: /
```

This way, not only you have a permanently running pod (which is the NFS server pod) for you to do the `kubectl cp`, you also have the opportunity to mount the same NFS volume to multiple pods concurrently since NFS does not have the single-mount restriction that most PVC drivers have.

N.B: I have been using this in-cluster NFS server technique for almost 5 years with no issues supporting production-grade traffic volumes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Restic](https://restic.net/) to backup your filesystem and restore it wherever you need to.

For creating backup, you can write a job like this:
first create the init job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: restic-init-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: restic/restic:0.14.0
        name: restic
        env:
        - name: RESTIC_PASSWORD
          value: "123"
        command: ["restic"]
        args: ["init", "--repo", "/tmp/backup"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: restic-backup
          mountPath: /tmp/backup/
      restartPolicy: OnFailure

      volumes:
       - name: restic-backup
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: restic-claim
```

then backup:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: restic-backup
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: restic/restic:0.14.0
        name: restic
        env:
        - name: RESTIC_PASSWORD
          value: "123"
        command: ["restic"]
        args: ["--repo", "/tmp/backup", "backup", "/bitnami/postgresql"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
          readOnly: true
        - name: restic-backup
          mountPath: /tmp/backup/
      restartPolicy: OnFailure

      volumes:
       - name: html
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: data-postgres-0
       - name: restic-backup
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: restic-claim
```

and for restoring:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: restic-restore
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: restic/restic:0.14.0
        name: restic
        env:
        - name: RESTIC_PASSWORD
          value: "123"
        command: ["restic"]
        args: ["--repo", "/tmp/backup", "restore", "latest", "--target", "/"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: html
          mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
        - name: restic-backup
          mountPath: /tmp/backup/
      restartPolicy: OnFailure

      volumes:
       - name: html
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: data-postgres-0
       - name: restic-backup
         persistentVolumeClaim:
           claimName: restic-claim
```